# My SQL Server 2008 R2 CLR works sometimes, but not others, but why?

Tags: sql-server, security, sql-server-2008-r2, sqlclr

I have a CLR DLL (called `clr.dll`) which we've previously loaded and used. I'm using it to load a large number of XML files (for which we have no XSD so we can't use the fiddly XML processor in SSIS as this requires an XSD). I'm loading it into a database also called CLR. For info the CLR function returns the XML file as a table by having one row per node. The CLR also has a few test functions

Previously this has worked and now it produces errors. The errors appear to occur intermittently, and occur even if the only thing executing on the server is a call to the CLR. I have a few test functions that use virtually no resource and they also don't work. i.e. it's not a resource problem.

The CLR is loaded with `PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS`. The database is set with `TRUSTWORTHY ON`. It appears that in SQL Server 2008 R2 we can't load the CLR using hashcode and my dll exceeds the 8000 chars that `HASHBYTES` supports anyway (suggested by other articles).

Within the CLR the functions belong to a class named `UserDefinedFunctions`.

This is a cut down version of the script I'm using to setup the CLR. The database has correct permissions. In summary it: (1) drops all functions in the CLR database, (2) drops and reconnects the CLR and (3) creates the functions to link to the assembly and sets the permissions on them appropriately.

```sql
USE CLR
GO

-- drop all functions
DECLARE @FunctionName NVARCHAR(400)
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

WHILE EXISTS    (SELECT *
                FROM    sysobjects
                WHERE   xtype IN ('FS', 'FT'))
BEGIN
    SET @FunctionName = (SELECT TOP 1 name
                        FROM    sysobjects
                        WHERE   xtype IN ('FS', 'FT'))

    SET @SQL = 'DROP FUNCTION dbo.' + @FunctionName

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
END 
GO

-- belt and braces, this should be the case anyway
ALTER DATABASE CLR SET TRUSTWORTHY ON;
GO

-- drops and load the assembly, first time
IF EXISTS   (SELECT *
            FROM    sys.assemblies
            WHERE   name = 'CLR')
    DROP ASSEMBLY CLR
GO

CREATE ASSEMBLY CLR from 'e:\clr\clr.dll' WITH PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS;
GO

-- ======== Scalar-functions ================================================================
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.DateTimeToString(@dt DATETIME, @fmt NVARCHAR(MAX)) RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS EXTERNAL NAME CLR.UserDefinedFunctions.DateTimeToString;
GO


CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FileExists(@Filename NVARCHAR(MAX)) RETURNS BIT
AS EXTERNAL NAME CLR.UserDefinedFunctions.FileExists;
GO


CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FileGetCreated(@Filename NVARCHAR(MAX)) RETURNS DATETIME
AS EXTERNAL NAME CLR.UserDefinedFunctions.FileGetCreated;
GO


CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FileGetModified(@Filename NVARCHAR(MAX)) RETURNS DATETIME
AS EXTERNAL NAME CLR.UserDefinedFunctions.FileGetModified;
GO


CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FileGetSize(@Filename NVARCHAR(MAX)) RETURNS BIGINT
AS EXTERNAL NAME CLR.UserDefinedFunctions.FileGetSize;
GO


CREATE FUNCTION Reflection(@Data NVARCHAR(MAX)) RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX) -- test - returns the string passed to it
AS EXTERNAL NAME CLR.UserDefinedFunctions.Reflection;
GO


-- ======== Table-valued functions -- ReadTextFile
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ReadTextFile(@Filename NVARCHAR(4000))
RETURNS 
TABLE
(
    LineIndex INT,
    Data NVARCHAR(4000)
)
AS
EXTERNAL NAME CLR.UserDefinedFunctions.ReadTextFile
GO


-- ReadXmlDoc
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ReadXmlDoc(@Filename NVARCHAR(4000))
RETURNS 
TABLE
(
    NodeIndex INT,
    ParentIndex INT,
    DepthIndex INT, 
    ChildCount INT, 
    SiblingIndex INT, 
    SiblingCount INT, 
    IsTerminalNode BIT,
    Tag NVARCHAR(4000),
    IndexPath NVARCHAR(4000),
    SimplePath NVARCHAR(4000), 
    UniquePath NVARCHAR(4000), 
    ExtendedPath NVARCHAR(4000), 
    TextValue NVARCHAR(4000)
)
AS
EXTERNAL NAME CLR.UserDefinedFunctions.ReadXmlDoc
GO

-- SELECT and EXECUTE permissions are set here, but omitted for security reasons
```

I'm then calling my minimal test function, named `Reflection`, which simply returns the string passed to it:

```sql
SELECT  CLR.dbo.Reflection('hello')
```

Irrespective of which function I call, or which database I execute in, this error is thrown:

> Msg 10314, Level 16, State 11, Line 1
>   An error occurred in the Microsoft .NET Framework while trying to load assembly id 65544. The server may be running out of resources, or the assembly may not be trusted with PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS or UNSAFE. Run the query again, or check documentation to see how to solve the assembly trust issues. For more information about this error:
>
> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'clr, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An error relating to security occurred. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013150A)
>   System.IO.FileLoadException:
>
> at System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection)
>   at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
>   at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
>   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)

As I say, it's not a resource issue and it's not a permissions issue and it happens "sometimes". Currently, I haven't been able to get it to run this week. Last week reapplying the drop and create scripts resolved the issue.

When I execute this code as suggested by Solomon below:

```sql
SELECT  name,
        is_trustworthy_on, 
        is_db_chaining_on, 
        compatibility_level, 
        owner_sid, 
        collation_name 
FROM    sys.databases 
WHERE   name IN (N'CLR', N'Other_DB')
```

I get:

```
name      is_trustworthy_on  is_db_chaining_on  compatibility_level  owner_sid                                                   collation_name
Other_DB  0                  0                  100                  0x0105000000000005150000009530FDDAA5F3AE3A5859ABA1C5FB0000  Latin1_General_CI_AS
CLR       1                  0                  100                  0x0105000000000005150000009530FDDAA5F3AE3A5859ABA17C2E0100  Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

Added 2 Oct 2019. Additionally, query 1:

```sql
SELECT  lgn.[name], 
        lgn.[type_desc], 
        lgn.[sid], 
        CASE lgn.[sid] WHEN SUSER_SID() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [IsCurrent] 
FROM    sys.server_principals lgn 
WHERE   lgn.[sid] IN (0x0105000000000005150000009530FDDAA5F3AE3A5859ABA1C5FB0000, 0x0105000000000005150000009530FDDAA5F3AE3A5859ABA17C2E0100, SUSER_SID());
```

Results 1:

```
name       type_desc      sid                                                         IsCurrent
GRP\clone  WINDOWS_LOGIN  0x0105000000000005150000009530FDDAA5F3AE3A5859ABA1C5FB0000  0
GRP\mark   WINDOWS_LOGIN  0x0105000000000005150000009530FDDAA5F3AE3A5859ABA1CD790200  1
```

Query 2:

```sql
USE [CLR];
GO

SELECT  DB_NAME() AS [DB], usr.[name], usr.[type_desc], usr.[sid], CASE usr.[sid] WHEN USER_SID() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [IsCurrent]
FROM    sys.database_principals usr 
WHERE   usr.[sid] IN (0x0105000000000005150000009530FDDAA5F3AE3A5859ABA1C5FB0000, 0x0105000000000005150000009530FDDAA5F3AE3A5859ABA17C2E0100, USER_SID()) 
OR      usr.[name] = N'dbo';
```

Results 2:

```
DB   name      type_desc     sid                                                         IsCurrent
CLR  dbo       WINDOWS_USER  0x0105000000000005150000009530FDDAA5F3AE3A5859ABA17C2E0100  0
CLR  GRP\mark  WINDOWS_USER  0x0105000000000005150000009530FDDAA5F3AE3A5859ABA1CD790200  1
```

Query 3:

```sql
USE [Other_DB];
GO

SELECT  DB_NAME() AS [DB], 
        usr.[name], 
        usr.[type_desc], 
        usr.[sid], 
        CASE usr.[sid] WHEN USER_SID() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [IsCurrent] 
FROM    sys.database_principals usr 
WHERE   usr.[sid] IN (0x0105000000000005150000009530FDDAA5F3AE3A5859ABA1C5FB0000, 0x0105000000000005150000009530FDDAA5F3AE3A5859ABA17C2E0100, USER_SID()) 
OR      usr.[name] = N'dbo';
```

Results 3:

```
DB        name  type_desc     sid                                                         IsCurrent
Other_DB  dbo   WINDOWS_USER  0x0105000000000005150000009530FDDAA5F3AE3A5859ABA1C5FB0000  0
```

Answer (score 0):

So I have learnt the following:

- the following applies to CLRs that are EXTERNAL_ACCESS or UNSAFE in SQL2008R2.
- when you create the assembly and connect SQL functions to a CLR, it doesn't load the CLR. This makes sense. Why use up memory before you need to.
- when you first execute a call to the CLR, it will check the SID of the database of the query being executed against the SID of the CLR database. These two SIDs may or may not be the same. A primary reason why they may be different is that the database the query is being run from may have been restored from another server. If they don't agree, this error occurs:

```
Msg 10314, Level 16, State 11, Line 1
An error occurred in the Microsoft .NET Framework while trying to load assembly id 65544. The server may be running out of resources, or the assembly may not be trusted with PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS or UNSAFE. Run the query again, or check documentation to see how to solve the assembly trust issues. For more information about this error: 
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'clr, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An error relating to security occurred. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013150A)
System.IO.FileLoadException: 
   at System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
```

- however, if you execute a function first in the CLR database,
  obviously the SID of the CLR database agrees with itself and so it
  loads the CLR happily.
- solutions exist using module signing, which I don't yet understand, but a short term work-around is to run a function from the CLR database as soon as you've created the assembly and created the functions.
- See here for more info:
  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2010/03/23/unable-to-load-clr-assembly-intermittently/
- See here for info on module signing: https://modulesigning.info/

Comment: Hi Mark. I have an idea re: what could be causing this, but can't reproduce the behavior based on your description. I have SQL Server 2008 R2 with a `CLR` DB set to `TRUSTWORTHY ON`, owned by `sa`, containing an unsigned, `UNSAFE` assembly and a SQLCLR stored proc that simply prints "Hello". I also have a `CLR_other` DB owned by a non-sysadmin SQL Server Login. If I am in `CLR_other`, I can `EXEC CLR.dbo.PrintHello;` and it works. `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_clr_appdomains;` returned 0 rows before I did the `EXEC`. Doesn't matter if I set `TRUSTWORTHY ON` or even EXEC as `CLR_other_owner`. (cont.)

Comment: So, I need more info. Please add the answers to the following to the main question: what does `SELECT [name], [is_trustworthy_on], [is_db_chaining_on], [compatibility_level], [owner_sid], [collation_name] FROM sys.databases WHERE [name] IN (N'CLR', N'other_DB');` (replace "other\_DB" with the DB that you get the error in) return? Is Cross-DB ownership enabled at the server level? If you exec the function in the CLR DB first, can you then: `USE [other_DB]; SELECT CLR.dbo.Reflection('hello')`? If you exec from other\_DB first (error), can you then `USE [CLR]; SELECT CLR.dbo.Reflection('hello')`?

Comment: Hi Solomon, thanks for the reply. Apologies for the delay - I've been on leave. So I'll answer your questions backwards. If I executed code in the CLR from the CLR database first, the CLR then works from other databases. However, if I try and execute code from Other_DB first, it fails from them on.

Comment: I've edited the answer above in response to the SQL query re DB chaining, so I can use the formatting tools.

Comment: Incidentally, I'm just working through your articles on CLR security on SQL Server Central. Well written and I'm learning. Thank you very much for putting in the effort.

Comment: Hi Mark. Thanks for adding that info to the question. Now, please paste in the results of this query: `SELECT lgn.[name], lgn.[type_desc], lgn.[sid], CASE lgn.[sid] WHEN SUSER_SID() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [IsCurrent]
FROM   sys.server_principals lgn
WHERE  lgn.[sid] IN (0x0105000000000005150000009530FDDAA5F3AE3A5859ABA1C5FB0000, 0x0105000000000005150000009530FDDAA5F3AE3A5859ABA17C2E0100, SUSER_SID());`. (continued...)

Comment: And then execute: `USE [CLR];

SELECT DB_NAME() AS [DB], usr.[name], usr.[type_desc], usr.[sid], CASE usr.[sid] WHEN USER_SID() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [IsCurrent]
FROM   sys.database_principals usr
WHERE  usr.[sid] IN (0x0105000000000005150000009530FDDAA5F3AE3A5859ABA1C5FB0000, 0x0105000000000005150000009530FDDAA5F3AE3A5859ABA17C2E0100, USER_SID())
OR     usr.[name] = N'dbo';`. (continued...)

Comment: And finally: `USE [Other_DB];

SELECT DB_NAME() AS [DB], usr.[name], usr.[type_desc], usr.[sid], CASE usr.[sid] WHEN USER_SID() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [IsCurrent]
FROM   sys.database_principals usr
WHERE  usr.[sid] IN (0x0105000000000005150000009530FDDAA5F3AE3A5859ABA1C5FB0000, 0x0105000000000005150000009530FDDAA5F3AE3A5859ABA17C2E0100, USER_SID())
OR     usr.[name] = N'dbo';`. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Solomon, queries and results are pasted in at the bottom of the original question. From inspection, the **SID** of the **dbo** of CLR is different to the **SID** of the **dbo** of **Other_DB**. I've changed the names somewhat for internal security purposes, but kept them consistent across the query results.

Comment: Mark, thanks for posting the query results. Very helpful. I think I might have found something, need to run a test. Just FYI: SIDs of `dbo` User do not need to match between DBs. Matching or not matching wouldn't affect anything here. I will let you know what I find.

Comment: Mark, I have not been able to reproduce this exactly, but I still have an idea as to the source of the issue. I have a setup that is nearly identical to yours but there must be sometime small still missing. I believe the key to the odd behavior is the owner of the `CLR` DB (i.e. `sys.databases.owner_sid` ending in "E0100"). This particular login does _not_ have an entry in `sys.server_principals` yet is allowed to own a database. The only way I can achieve that is to set the owner of a DB to a Windows account that I haven't set up as a Login within SQL Server. Seeing that the `CLR` DB (cont..)

Comment: has `TRUSTWORTHY ON`, that requires the `dbo` SID of the `CLR` DB to have at least `EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY` permission. This Login doesn't exist in SQL Server, so it can't have any permissions. I was only able to get around this by creating a Windows Group, adding the Windows account that owns the `CLR` DB to that Windows Group, then adding a Login for the group in SQL Server, and adding that Windows Group-based Login to the `sysadmin` role. But then I couldn't get the SQLCLR object to fail when called from another DB. So I have a few more questions (in the next comment):

Comment: **1)** Are you currently able to drop and recreate the Assembly in the `CLR` database? **2)** Are there any NTFS file system permissions differences between the `GRP\clone`, `GRP\mark`, and the owner of the `CLR` DB? **3)** Is it only `Other_DB` that has a problem, or do you also get the error when in `master`? **4)**  What is the output of `EXEC xp_logininfo  N'GRP\CLR_db_owner';`? **5)** How do you reset between tests? Restart instance? `DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE(N'all');`? **6)** As a test, can you try changing the `CLR` DB owner to `sa`? **7)** What OS is SQL Server running on?

Comment: Also, if you aren't sure which Windows account is the owner of the `CLR` DB, you can use the following to get it from Windows: `SELECT SUSER_SNAME({owner_sid});`. That might help with question #4 directly above. AND, re: question #6, instead of changing the owner to `sa`, do you mind first trying to create a Login for that Windows account: `CREATE LOGIN [windows_account_name_for_CLR_owner] FROM WINDOWS;`, then: `USE [master]; GRANT EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY TO [login_for_CLR_owner];`. If that doesn't work: `USE [master]; GRANT AUTHENTICATE SERVER TO [login_for_CLR_owner];`. Else, try `sa`.

Comment: Hi Solomon, thanks for your help with this. We seem to have resolved the issue by changing the owner of the CLR database to be sa. This appears to have worked on both ur dev and production support servers. I'm not a DBA myself and our DBA has to work within our security environment, which can be a little restrictive and it takes time to be able to test. (cont...)

Comment: Without going into specific usernames, the owner of the CLR database until now is an AD account with elevated permissions that is used for promoting scripts. You are right. It doesn't have an entry as a server principal. I'm not quite sure why this is the case, but the method we use for promotions is to use a web portal to run scripts from a specific folder location. All scripts and results are then logged. The database owner is the AD account that this uses to run, but has no server principal mapped to it. (cont...)

Comment: Answering your questions: (1) I can drop and recreate the assembly in the CLR database. (2) Frustratingly from a developer point of view, I cannot see any of the file system on the server and so cannot answer this question. Makes sense from a security point of view though. (3) The error occurs in all database that are not the CLR database. (cont...)

Comment: (4) I can only execute xp_logininfo on our dev server, but this does reveal that the owner of the CLR database has a [permission path] that is an AD group which does have a server principal mapped to it, and that server principal has sysadmin server role. (cont...)

Comment: (5) I can't restart the server without DBA help and we have about a dozen developers working on it. All user connections are dropped each evening, and it appears that the assembly is uncached overnight, so I can effectively retest the next morning (it fails unless I call it from CLR). Or, I can repromote the scripts that drop and create the CLR database and functions/permissions etc. (6) Yes, this appears to work so far. (7) I think it's Windows Server 2012. (cont...)

Comment: In summary, I think we've found a solution by changing the owner to sa, which I believe our DBA is happy with. I don't quite understand why it doesn't work - you can probably enlighten me - but it appears to be linked to the fact that the database owner doesn't have a server principal. Thank you for your help - not an easy one to track down.

Comment: Thanks for that info. Glad that `sa` works. Though not sure that the issue is the db owner not having an associated server principal. Did you see my final message before your replies? I had suggested another test to create a server principal for that SID prior to trying `sa`. That would have told us if not having a server principal was the issue or not. This might have something to do with that specific AD account. I think the main factor here is `TRUSTWORTHY ON` for the CLR db: that causes an extra security check. I know that you have a solution now, but are you able to do this test? (cont.)

Comment: Also, **8)** Prior to setting db owner to `sa`, if you initially ran from `other_DB` (hence failure), would it then also fail if ran from within `CLR` db? Or did it just fail until run from within `CLR` db? **9)** Is your login a sysadmin in SQL Server? I noticed that you have a database principal in the `CLR` db but not `other\_DB`. Not sure if that is a factor in this.

Answer (score 0):

Testing has confirmed that this issue is directly related to the owner of the database containing the SQLCLR Assembly (the `CLR` database, in this case). Initially the `CLR` DB was owned by a Windows (Active Directory / AD) account. After switching the database owner over to `sa`, this behavior stopped happening.

While the problem area has been narrowed down (i.e. database owner where Assembly is located), and a solution found (i.e. change db owner to `sa`), the exact set of circumstances that cause this behavior has not yet been determined, and I am so far unable to reproduce this behavior based on the information provided.

For the moment, I am also fairly certain that the `TRUSTWORTHY ON` setting for the db containing the Assembly (the `CLR` DB) is a primary factor. I believe that when `TRUSTWORTHY` is enabled, Assemblies set to either `EXTERNAL_ACCESS` or `UNSAFE` do an extra, and external, security check. `TRUSTWORTHY` is only be used here due to the Assembly not being signed. I believe that if `TRUSTWORTHY` were `OFF` (i.e. disabled), then the owner of the database would *not* be a factor, and this behavior wouldn't even be possible in the first place.

**OTHER NOTES**

- The term "CLR" should not be used in this context. Terminology should be "Assemblies", "SQLCLR objects", ".NET code", or just "SQLCLR" in general. The CLR is the "Common Language Runtime" that executes the code compiled into the Assemblies. This is similar to the JVM for Java, and we wouldn't refer to Java programs or apps as "JVMs".
- > when you create the assembly and connect SQL functions to a CLR, it doesn't load the CLR.

  No, but only because the CLR is loaded when SQL Server starts and is running the entire time (unless you have "lightweight pooling" / "fiber mode" enabled, and you shouldn't).

  Also, when you either `CREATE` or `ALTER` an Assembly, an App Domain *is* created as the assembly needs to be validated. But, the Assembly itself is not loaded into the App Domain.
- > when you first execute a call to the CLR, it will check the SID of the database of the query being executed against the SID of the CLR database.

  No. The SID of the owner of the "current" DB is not checked (well, not unless there is Cross-DB ownership chaining is being used, and that is not the case here). The SID of the owner of the DB containing the Assembly is checked against the `owner_sid` record in `sys.databases` to make sure they match, but *only* when `TRUSTWORTHY` is enabled. In such cases, if the owner SID does not match between `sys.databases` and `sys.database_principals` (in the DB containing the Assembly), then you will get an error stating that those SIDs must match.

  > These two SIDs may or may not be the same. A primary reason why they may be different is that the database the query is being run from may have been restored from another server.

  Not exactly. The owner is initially set by the Login that created (via `CREATE DATABASE`, attach, or restore) the DB. However, it is fairly easy to change the owner of a database, and so I wouldn't assume that a DB came from another server simply due to having a different owner.

  > If they don't agree, this error occurs:

  No. There is no requirement that the owners of these two databases be the same.
- Regarding the "drop all functions" block of code shown in the top code block of the main question:

  1. Do not use `sysobjects` / `dbo.sysobjects` / `sys.sysobjects` as that is a compatibility view that exists only to allow for backwards compatibility with code written for versions of SQL Server prior to version 2005 (9.0). Starting in SQL Server 2005, you should be using `sys.objects`, or `sys.{anything}` instead of the old `sys{anything}` views.
  2. The datatype for `@FunctionName` should be `sysname` (which is a synonym for `NVARCHAR(128)` ) as that is used for nearly all entity names in SQL Server.
  3. Don't look simply for objects of a certain type as that is not very robust / stable since it can't distinguish between T-SQL wrapper objects associated with different Assemblies. You only have one Assembly now, but it's still an unnecessarily overly simplistic approach when the preferred approach is almost no extra effort. You should start with the `sys.assembly_modules` system catalog view. For example:

     ```sql
     SELECT obj.[name]
     FROM   sys.assembly_modules asmd
     INNER JOIN sys.assemblies assm
             ON assm.[assembly_id] = asmd.[assembly_id]
     INNER JOIN sys.objects obj
             ON obj.[object_id] = asmd.[object_id]
     WHERE  assm.[name] = N'{assembly_name_here}'
     ```

     Starting with that query it's easy to get the schema name from `obj.[schema_id]` and/or use a `CASE` statement to switch the object type for the `DROP` statement between `FUNCTION`, `PROCEDURE`, `TRIGGER`, depending on what is needed.
  4. I know this is just a deployment script, but still, instead of using a slow, row-by-row loop, you can drop all functions in a single batch / execution:

     ```sql
     DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

     SELECT @SQL += N'DROP FUNCTION dbo.' + obj.[name] + N';'
                    + NCHAR(0x0D) + NCHAR(0x0A) -- CR+LF
     FROM   sys.assembly_modules asmd
     INNER JOIN sys.assemblies assm
             ON assm.[assembly_id] = asmd.[assembly_id]
     INNER JOIN sys.objects obj
             ON obj.[object_id] = asmd.[object_id]
     WHERE  assm.[name] = N'{assembly_name_here}';

     PRINT @SQL; -- DEBUG (else comment out and UNcomment line below)
     --EXEC (@SQL);
     ```
- `SET TRUSTWORTHY ON` should be avoided, if at all possible. Please see "[PLEASE, Please, please Stop Using Impersonation, TRUSTWORTHY, and Cross-DB Ownership Chaining](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/12/30/please-please-please-stop-using-impersonation-execute-as/)" for details. Instead, sign the assembly with a certificate (i.e. [Module Signing](https://modulesigning.info/)). Please see:

  - [SQLCLR vs. SQL Server 2017, Part 2: “CLR strict security” – Solution 1](https://SqlQuantumLeap.com/2017/08/09/sqlclr-vs-sql-server-2017-part-2-clr-strict-security-solution-1/)
  - [SQLCLR vs. SQL Server 2017, Part 3: “CLR strict security” – Solution 2](https://SqlQuantumLeap.com/2017/08/16/sqlclr-vs-sql-server-2017-part-3-clr-strict-security-solution-2/)
- While this is mentioned in the two posts noted directly above, I find it *much* better to deploy an assembly from a `VARBINARY` literal (a.k.a. hex bytes) rather than from a DLL on the file system because that external DLL is now a dependency of the script and can even get out of sync with the creation of the T-SQL wrapper objects in the script. It's also harder to version the deployment script and/or transport it between systems. To easily convert the compiled DLL into a deployable `VARBINARY` literal, please see the open source tool I created for this purpose: [BinaryFormatter](https://github.com/SqlQuantumLeap/BinaryFormatter/releases/latest).
- For more info on working with SQLCLR in general, please visit: [SQLCLR Info](https://sqlclr.org/)